# RETURN QUERY vs RETURN QUERY EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql

> [PostgreSQL 39.6. Control Structures:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) RETURN QUERY has a variant RETURN QUERY EXECUTE, which specifies the query to be **executed dynamically**. Parameter expressions can be inserted into the computed query string via USING, in just the same way as in the EXECUTE command.

But what means **dynamically**?

What is a difference between these two statements (inside function with `func_param` parameter):

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_col = func_param;
```

and

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_col = $1' USING func_param;
```

?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between these two examples is that in the first one, the query plan can be retained and reused for future executions in the same database session.

In the second example, the query will be planned every time the function is executed.

The advantage of the first example is that you save planning time if the function is executed repeatedly. From the sixth execution on, PostgreSQL may choose to use a *generic plan* (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-prepare.html)) which will be use for all future executions in the same database session.

The second example is only useful if the chosen generic plan proves bad, and you'd rather have PostgreSQL replan the query every time.

Comment: The second option is useful when SQL is built dynamically. It is also useful when planner chooses different plans when query parameters are replaced by constants in cases like "WHERE param IS NULL OR field = param" where the planner can completely remove either left or right part of the filter should param be replaced by a constant.

Comment: Nice explanation. Actually, the second one takes much more time if the data volume is increased. This problem I fetched one of my LIVE project having millions of users.

For first one types of query take <200 ms whereas the second type of query takes 14 seconds