# postgresql : Same raw query run faster than in function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Same query run faster outside of function but in function it runs hundred times slower and when I remove where clause it runs faster in function too but not faster than raw query. I wonder whats the problem.

```
RETURN QUERY (SELECT 
    t.tran_id,  t.tran_date,  t.value_date, t.statement_reference, t.debit,   t.credit,t.office_id
FROM transactions.transactions_view t
WHERE t.tran_date BETWEEN from_::date AND to_::date

 AND t.gl_account_id = gl_account_id_);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (SELECT 
    t.tran_id,  t.tran_date,  t.value_date, t.statement_reference, t.debit, t.credit,t.office_id
FROM transactions.transactions_view t
WHERE t.tran_date BETWEEN from_::date AND to_::date
 AND t.gl_account_id = gl_account_id_);
```

See [RETURN QUERY vs RETURN QUERY EXECUTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739521/return-query-vs-return-query-execute) and [PostgreSQL: Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

Comment: Reading this comment: [Nice explanation. Actually, the second one (with EXECUTE) takes much more time if the data volume is increased. This problem I fetched one of my LIVE project having millions of users. For first one types of query take <200 ms whereas the second type of query takes 14 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739521/return-query-vs-return-query-execute#comment120449212_39740198) the real answer might be (at least a bit) more complex.

Comment: later when I was checking the query I found that there is problem with one date range when I pass the date between '2022-10-29' AND '2022-11-20' then it works fine and it generates result within 2 sec but when I change the date range between '2022-10-29' AND '2022-11-20' it takes more than 8 minutes to generate the results.